# Can I lock my screen with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, password, screen-lock, screensaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a quick way to lock my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64/is-there-a-quick-way-to-lock-my-mac)

I'm running OS X 10.7.3

Currently I've found what looks like 2 possible solutions:

1. Hot corner(s) setup in the "Desktop & Screen Savers" preferences
2. Create a service with Automator then map a keyboard shortcut in "Keyboard" preferences

I don't like 1 because it requires the mouse, and 2 seems like a bit of a hack. Is there a built in way to do this? Or should I settle for the workarounds?

Thanks
L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>eject</kbd>  (    sleep displays ) solve your problem?    (if you set authentication for login)

Or you can use <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>eject</kbd>    Put the computer to sleep.

Comment: Do you know of a way to customize this shortcut?  Thanks!