# What is the (external) keyboard shortcut to lock my screen with the screen save

Tags: keyboard

Which keys can I press to bring up the locked screen save while I walk away for a few minutes?
I have an external keyboard (MS Comfort Curve 2000) thru a multi pc switcher box so I have ctrl-cmd-alt keys but no option key and everything I've tried so far doesn't work.

Comment: There's no default shortcut for it (unless you count ⌃⇧⏏ and ⌥⌘⏏ when requiring a password after sleep is enabled), but see [Is there a quick way to lock my Mac?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64/is-there-a-quick-way-to-lock-my-mac). One option would be assign a custom shortcut to `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend`.

Comment: FWIW, Alt and Option are the same key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Eject</kbd> to put your display to sleep but also to lock your screen. If you don't have an Eject key, you need to use an [Automator based workaround](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090831093941225) to assign your own shortcut. Alternatively, you can set a Hot Corner for the screensaver to start in System Preferences.

For the locking to work, you have to tell OS X to require a password immediately after sleep in *System Preferences > Security & Privacy*:

[image]

When this is set, the above key combo will lock your screen and a password is required to unlock it.

Comment: this assumes the user has an Eject key; from his post it sounds like he is not using an Apple external keyboard as he doesn't have an Option key.

Comment: indeed, thanks. Updated the answer with the easiest workaround I could find by just using the Start Screensaver action

Answer (score 8):

Open `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` -> `App Shortcuts`.  Then click on the plus  sign under the white box that has the different options in there.  Name it 'Sleep' and give it the ⌘⌥F12 command (cmd + opt + F12).  You can set it to whatever you like but most keyboards already map F12 to the eject key so if you get a different keyboard it may work already by default.  Remember to also change your settings to require your password after a set time after going to sleep.  Hope this helps, I searched for awhile to find out how to do this and couldn't find any good answers.[image]

Comment: This worked for me, so thanks for this.  I had to close out of System Preferences before it would work--it doesn't seem to apply immediately.

Comment: Glad that worked for you.  Drove me insane trying to figure it out

Comment: It does NOT work in certain apps even after defining ⌘⌥F12  shortcut - e.g. Google Chrome. Also - it works only with ⌘⌥F12 for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're up for using an external program, [Karabiner-elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) makes this super simple.

I've installed it and imported [PC-Style Shortcuts](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/), which maps it to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Big benefit of Karabiner is that it's flexible enough that you can enable/disable this on a per-keyboard basis (I keep the defaults for my Mac keyboard, and use PC style on my external "Windows" keyboard). Also, you can enable-disable individual rules, or create your own shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

A bit out of the box but this could work:

If you have an iPhone or iPad you could set up iCloud and find my mac, iPhone, iPad.
boot up the `find my iPhone app` on your iDevice and lock your mac from there while you walk away.

Or if your not afraid for some apple scripting and you have a bluetooth enabled mac you could use this script to lock your mac upon bluetooth disconnection. ( which also should work with an non apple phone ) more info about the scripting can be found here: [Lock and unlock a Mac using Bluetooth detection](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20091221173111783)

Answer (score 0):

Richi Jeffery provided a great answer to this, but that puts your computer to Sleep, which means it takes a few seconds to wake up when you return.  You can do the same but do a Lock Screen instead which wakes up instantly when you return.  Also on the laptop keyboard, the Lock Screen command is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift+</kbd>Power.  The closest to that on my Windows Keyboard is <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> so I've used that.

Here's Richi's answer edited with the changes:

1. Open **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**.
2. Click on the plus sign under the white box that has the different options in there.
3. Name it "Lock Screen" and give it the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd> +<kbd>F12</kbd>. You can set it to whatever you like but most keyboards already map <kbd>F12</kbd> to the <kbd>Eject</kbd> key so if you get a different keyboard it may work already by default.

Remember to also change your settings to require your password after a set time after going to sleep.

[image: Screenshot Of Lock Screen Shortcut Setting]