# How to lock MacBook with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: automator, script, screen-lock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a quick way to lock my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64/is-there-a-quick-way-to-lock-my-mac)

I am familiar with using Automator, but I do not know what code should be used to accomplish the feature. Can anyone provide the code used to lock my retina MacBook Pro? I want a function similar to the one in Windows when you press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: What sort of "macbook" you mean matters here, as well as what you mean by "lock" it. What hardware do you have, and what do you hope locking the machine will accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps, on 10.7 Lion, I just use a global two-key shortcut in [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) (free/donationware) to start the screen saver and lock my Mac. You'll also need "Require password for sleep and screen saver" set to "immediately" in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General. The shortcut shown here is <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> which I prefer to other solutions as its virtually the same key positions for my Windows and Mac machines!

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⏏</kbd>/<kbd>⌽</kbd> (eject key, or power key on Macbook Air) to put the display to sleep immediately (this also requires "Require password for sleep and screen saver" set to "immediately" in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General).

Comment: Perfect. I always had BTT but never thought they had the option for `Switch to Login Screen` which does the exact thing !!

Comment: Not the exact thing: the login screen disconnects wifi, the lock screen does not.