# MacBook Pro lock screen hotkey without sleeping?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, display, sleep-wake

I'd like to press a key combo to get my computer to the lock screen. In Windows the shortcut was <kbd>Windows key</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. On Mac I press <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>Power</kbd> which turns the laptop off and puts it into sleep. I want to just have it go to the lock screen with the monitor staying on.

Comment: I think [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64/is-there-a-quick-way-to-lock-my-mac) might help.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**High Sierra and higher(?)**

As usual every system update changes something.
There is now a Apple Menu item <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> that locks the screen!

**Sierra and lower**

You can add the Lock Screen to your Menubar.

- In Spotlight (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) search for `Keychain Access`
- Open Preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>)
- Check `Show keychain status in menu bar` This will show a lock in your Menu Bar with an option `Lock Screen`

  (Optional)
- `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` or `Keyboard` Tab
- In the `App Shortcuts` or `Application Shortcuts` section, add a new item for `All Applications` with the Menu Title of `Lock Screen` and a Keyboard shortcut that you like.
  [image: Example]

This way you don't have to change your Screensaver timeout and you can lock your machine much like you do in windows. Note that You may also need to Logout and back in for any changes to the shortcut to take effect.

Comment: A small addition for Yosemite. To add the keyboard shortcut as in the second half of hoss' answer go to `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts`, click on `App Shortcuts` -> `All Applications` and then add the keyboard shortcut as above.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer to include the language change between versions.

Comment: A slight typing mistake .."Show Status in Menu Bar" should be "Show keychain status in menu bar".

Comment: Depends on the version of the OS, apple likes to change the language slightly between releases. However you are right, starting from at least 10.9 it was changed to 'Show keychain status in menu bar'

Comment: Another option that I use is the free quick launcher Alfred (free), which includes a Lock command. https://www.alfredapp.com/

Comment: the High Sierra changed the options in key chains.  I can't find it any longer.

Comment: Yeah in High Sierra it's now Shift + Command + Q, IIRC

Comment: @hoss Shift + Command + Q logs out instead of locking the screen

Comment: @JonathanReez yeah meant Control not Shift.

Answer (score 25):

I have finally figured out how to do this:

```
pmset displaysleepnow
```

That will actually put the display to sleep without suspending the entire machine.

Amazing how hard it is to figure out how to do something so basic.

Comment: @eveo this is the same as control+shift+eject. Display sleep, but not computer sleep.

Comment: Mac OS X seems to have different ways of doing everything, which is kind of frustrating. I want to like it, but one of the huge benefits of Windows is having common APIs for many different types of operations (eg. WMI, performance metrics, etc.).

Comment: Is there an equivalent for the MacBook (which doesn't have an eject key)? On my Sierra 10.12.3, the Ctrl+Shift+Power shortcut puts the laptop to sleep. I see that because the VPN gets disconnected. This doesn't happen for "pmset displaysleepnow".

Comment: Also, to make it so you can run this with a keystroke, use Automator to create a service. I did something like this https://arstechnica.com/apple/2011/03/howto-build-mac-os-x-services-with-automator-and-shell-scripting/
Once you have that you can give it a shortcut in the Keyboard settings.
And totally non-intuitive, of course. I've had to reconfigure my macbook twice and each time I had to go google this up again.

Comment: @BHS I have been looking for this for years, thanks! If I change my sleep settings to "never" sleep, in combination with this can I be assured that any processes I have running in background keep running while displaysleep is ON? On my MBP, this also locks the screen, which is awesome!!! That way I can keep working on the machine which is in sleep via a ssh connection, and not worry about burning extra power.

Answer (score 8):

This is now built into High Sierra.

The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

I use [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de) to do just this. Once downloaded and running:

1. Click the "Keyboard" tab and select "Global" in the left-hand "Select Application" pane
2. Click "+ Add new keyboard shortcut" at the bottom of the shortcut list
3. Click the "Keyboard shortcut" recording field and hold down the keys you wish to use for the shortcut, I use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (which feels most like the Windows key + L on Windows systems)
4. Click the "Trigger predefined action" dropdown and select "Open application/file/script..."
5. Navigate to /System/Library/Frameworks/Screensaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources and select "ScreenSaverEngine.app" and click "Open"

Alternatively, instead of steps 4 and 5, click the "Trigger predefined action" dropdown and select "Lock Screen" which locks the screen without triggering the screensaver.

Now hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will trigger the screensaver (and lock the computer, provided you followed the advice in the answer from @Buscar 웃 above to require the password when the screen saver or display sleep begins). You can also set BetterTouchTool to launch when the computer starts so your hotkey always works.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should enable requiring the password when the screen saver or display sleep begins.

To do that go to

[image: screenshot of Security & Privacy > General]

Now, when you press the key combination <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd> (<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⏏</kbd> on some systems) to put the screen to sleep, it will also lock the screen.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want it blacking my screen and keyboard out. I thought I made that clear in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting myself from https://github.com/tjluoma/lockscreen:

1. Download and install [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) (which is free for up to 10 keyboard shortcuts)
2. Download and install [LockScreen.scpt](https://github.com/tjluoma/lockscreen/blob/master/LockScreen.scpt) and save it to ~/Library/Scripts/ (you may have to create that folder if you haven't used it before.
3. Assign the keyboard shortcut of your choice to `LockScreen.scpt` within FastScripts preferences:

[image: FastScripts preferences screenshot]

Note: while the OP did not want to sleep the screen display, that can easily be done too. Just download [Sleep Display](http://tobiastom.github.io/Sleep-Display/) and install it to /Applications/ and use [SleepAndLockScreen.scpt](https://github.com/tjluoma/lockscreen/blob/master/SleepAndLockScreen.scpt) instead of `LockScreen.scpt`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a wonderful tool [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) that can help you with this (and many more):

Properties->Misc&Uninstall -> private.xml

```
<root>
<!-- Place this file to ~/Library/Application Support/Karabiner/private.xml -->
  <item>
      <item>
        <name>Screensaver Lock screen (Ctrl-Cmd-L)</name>
        <identifier>myconfig.lock</identifier>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::L, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,
                                KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_APP_ScreenSaverEngine</autogen>
      </item>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then activate the `Screensaver Lock screen (Ctrl-Cmd-L)` in the `Change Key` screen.

**Update [1 Feb 2018]:** The Karabiner was deprecated and replaced with [Karabiner-elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). So achieving this may be as simple as mapping the MAC `POWER` button to some button on the keyboard. I use `PAUSE` button for that. Then locking screen would be `Ctrl-Shift-Power` and suspending - `Cmd-Opt-Power`.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend using Hot Corners: System Preferences -> Desktop & Screen Saver -> Hot Corners (in the bottom right corner). There you can select an option for the corner you want to. "Lock Screen" or "Put Display to Sleep".

Answer (score 0):

Logging out to the fast user switching screen:

- Add a shell alias or a keyboard shortcut for `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend`.
- Enable the fast user switching menu from the Users & Groups preference pane, and then select Login Window… from the menu.
- Use the lock action in Alfred.

Locking the screen:

- Check "Require password immediately after sleep or screen saver begins" in the Security & Privacy preference pane. You can then lock the computer manually by pressing control-shift-eject to turn off displays, by pressing option-command-eject to go to sleep, or by running `open -a ScreenSaverEngine`.
- Enable the Keychain menu extra in the preferences of Keychain Access, and then select Lock Screen from the menu.