# How to prevent Cisco AnyConnect from disconnecting when locking screen

Tags: network, vpn, screen-lock

My Mac Book pro with 10.11.2 has this annoying feature that it disconnects Cisco AnyConnect VPN every time I lock the screen.

I found some instructions on how to prevent Wi-Fi disconnection when locking the screen, but I could not apply those instructions to the AnyConnect network. I´m usually connected with Ethernet cable, if that matters.

Is there some way to disable such feature?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 14):

### TL;DR

Launch Terminal and run:

```
ifconfig | grep -B 6 'status: active' | head -n 1 | cut -d : -f 1
```

Then run (replace `en0` below with the output of the command above):

```
cd /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources
sudo ./airport en0 prefs DisconnectOnLogout=NO
sudo pmset -a sleep 0
```

---

### Long version

I am on MacOS Mojave (10.14).
For me this helped against automatically disconnecting from Cisco AnyConnect while on WiFi:

Open the **Terminal** app and paste:

```
ifconfig | grep -B 6 'status: active' | head -n 1 | cut -d : -f 1
```

This returned:

```
en0
```

Then type (replace `en0` on line 2 with the returned value above):

```
cd /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources
sudo ./airport en0 prefs DisconnectOnLogout=NO
```

Type your password.
Check if the setting was saved by typing:

```
sudo ./airport prefs
```

Which should return this:

```
AirPort preferences for en0:

DisconnectOnLogout=NO
Unable to retrieve JoinMode
JoinModeFallback=DoNothing
RememberRecentNetworks=YES
RequireAdminIBSS=NO
RequireAdminNetworkChange=NO
RequireAdminPowerToggle=NO
WoWEnabled=YES
```

`DisconnectOnLogout` should be set to `NO`.

Next, prevent the system from going to sleep after locking:

```
sudo pmset -a sleep 0
```

That should do the trick, worked for me.

Comment: FYI the ifconfig cutting command given sometimes picks the wrong interface. Sometimes many interfaces are active, and sometimes there are more of less than 6 lines preceding "status: active".

Comment: Imagine Googling for this problem, finding the same answer, trying it, failing in the same way, debugging it, and then coming here to leave a comment... and then discovering that you already left one almost four years ago. :facepalm

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem - my internet connection is 10/100 USB LAN.  If I have Cisco anyconnect connected to the vpn and lock the screen it drops the vpn.  The screensaver locking it seemed to not disconnect.

I am on 10.11.6 - El Capitan.

I use the lock screen solution described here:

[MBP Lock screen hotkey without sleeping?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95819/mbp-lock-screen-hotkey-without-sleeping)

Did you find a solution?  This is widely reported when people have wifi connections and lock the screen but there seem to be many potential solutions with nothing definitive.  Your post seems to be somewhat unique in that it is a wired setup like mine.  Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the free version of [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) by

1. Forcing password on the screen saver in the OS settings (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204379)
2. Disabling Alfred from controlling the OS X `Lock` (optional)
3. Setting up Alfred to use `lock` or `l` (I use the latter) for controlling the screen saver

[image]

I understand this method won't work without Alfred, but I find it very a convenient way to quickly lock my screen without dropping VPN connections. I also understand that there may be differences in how this method differs from the OS X `Lock` functionality.