# Lock the screen of a Mac without hanging up FaceTime

Tags: facetime, screen-lock

According to this [method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95819/macbook-pro-lock-screen-hotkey-without-sleeping), one can lock the Mac without putting it into sleep by pressing <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. However, it will terminate the FaceTime call immediately. Is there a way to keep the FaceTime alive when locking the screen like the iPhone does?

Comment: When you include a link in your question or answer, it is best to include the relevant and important parts of the material at that link either by quoting directly or summarizing them in your own words. This is helpful and important because the original material may be removed or the link get broken sooner or later after you use it. In addition, it may not be clear which part of the material at that link you are referring to.

Comment: Perhaps the act of locking also turns off the camera. Is the green camera LED extinguished when you execute that key combo? Out of curiosity, why do you want to lock the screen?

Comment: @IconDaemon, the green LED is also turned off when I execute the key combo. But I only want to keep the audio. I'm just curious why a Mac can't do it as an iPhone does.

Comment: Perhaps Apple decided that it would be a privacy problem, i.e. a way to 'spy' using a computer which looks like it is not running. I've done a bit of sleuthing, but can't find anything definitive about this,

Comment: Thanks. That makes very much sense.