# Keyboard shortcut for locking screen in macOS Sierra?

Tags: keyboard, sleep-wake, shortcut, macos

In previous versions of OSX, I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>  <kbd>Power</kbd> on my built in keyboard, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>  <kbd>Eject</kbd> on my (old) Apple bluetooth keyboard to lock the screen.

After upgrading to Sierra, that shortcut stopped working. Using *Karabiner-EventViewer* I discovered that pressing the built in power button triggers `SysKey 0x6`, and the Bluetooth keyboard <kbd>Eject</kbd> triggers no events.

Whats going on, and how can re-enable that shortcut?

Comment: How do you feel about shareware utilities?

Comment: I had a similar problem with MacBook Pro (that has eject key on built-in keyboard) and a wired Apple keyboard. External keyboard's ctrl+shift+eject didn't do anything. Then I tried the same shortcut with the built-in keyboard, which worked—and, to my surprise, *after this* the shortcut worked also with the external keyboard! (Also I noted I had to hold the shortcut about 0,5 seconds longer than before.) Have you tried this? If it works, I can submit this as an answer…

Comment: Just tried to press Ctrl + Shift + Power on built-in keyboard of my MBL15 and it locked the screen. However, I used to a shorter shortcut :) - Hot Corner: quickly put mouse cursor to down right corner (you can choose to your taste) and screen locks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a quick way to lock my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64/is-there-a-quick-way-to-lock-my-mac)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are different ways to lock your screen.

**Note: These shortcut tips are for Sierra and below. In High Sierra, there is a new entry under the Apple Menu (with shortcut) to lock the screen.**

**1. Use keychain**

Open keychain -> Settings. Choose from there **Show keychain status in menu bar**.

[image]

You can now choose from the menu bar to lock your screen.

[image]

With this option, you need your password to log in next time.

**2. Use Hot Corners to lock your screen**

First, go to your System Settings -> Desktop & Screen Saver and choose Hot Corners on the bottom right.

[image]

Next, choose one of the corners the option **Put Display to Sleep**. I prefer bottom right, but this is by each user different.

[image]

That's all. One note: You can configure in the Privacy Settings when the display will be locked. For example, if you have it set to five minutes, you need to enter your password after the time in your setting is gone. You can change this to immediately, for example.

[image]

**3. Lock Screen (with Shortcut)**

Because @Flimm asked for a shortcut to lock the screen, here is a solution below High Sierra.

Usually, there are two solutions. You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Power Button</kbd> or

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd>-Key to lock the screen.

Both solutions are not my favourites, and for that reason, I've created a Shell Script with Automator. Thanks to [Taylor](http://blog.taylormcgann.com/author/tmcgann/) who gave me this hint.

1. Open Spotlight and type **Automator** to open the Application.
2. Create a new Document.
3. Choose **Service** to make as global Service.
4. On the left Pane, choose **Utilities**; and on the right column, double-click **Run Shell Script**. You see a Window with the Cat-Command.
5. Delete the cat-Command and copy & paste the following Shell-Script into the empty Window:

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend`

**Make sure that on the top right of the Automator-Window, both pull down-menus are set as <kbd>no input</kbd> in <kbd>any application</kbd>**.

6. Click on the top right to the Run-Button (marked with green circle) and test if it works.
7. Save your workflow now as Lock Screen, for example.
8. Open System Preferences, Keyboard and click on the Button Shortcuts or Keyboard Shortcuts.
9. Choose on the Left columns Services and search for your saved workflow.
10. Add your favourite Shortcut (e.g. I have Cmd + Alt/Opt + L).

***For better understanding, I have put the pictures below.***

[image]

[image]

[Apple Support Documents Mac Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

Comment: How to open that keychain?

Comment: Type in Spotlight **keychain** and hit Enter. Or choose from the Finder-Menu -> Go To -> **Utilities** and open from there keychain.

Comment: There's a `Keychain Access`....

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean. Have you problem to Access your keychain? Maybe this help you: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH20094?locale=de_DE&viewlocale=en_EN

Comment: I couldn't find such option in Keychain preferences in High Sierra, have they moved it somewhere else?

Comment: This post does not answer the question: how do you enable a keyboard shortcut to lock the user out?

Comment: @iosdude, You don't need this in High Sierra.  There is a Lock Screen menu option in the apple menu (works globally).

Comment: I had no idea this is so idiotic. How about WinKey+L on Windows  Built into every Windows OS since 1995.

Answer (score 44):

In macOS High Sierra (10.13) there is a 'Lock Screen' option built in the Apple menu.

And finally a shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> :-)

[image: Lock Screen in Apple Menu]

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out!  I've only been running 10.13 for a couple of days and this one change has made the upgrade worthwhile.  :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the combination, just realized `^` is actually `ctrl` (new to mac)

Comment: And that funny-looking branch thing is Option. Took me a while to figure that out. (:

Answer (score 16):

If you have a 2016 or later MacBook Pro with Touch Bar, you can assign one of the Touch Bar virtual keys to lock the Mac. It's under System Preferences/Keyboard and use the "Customize Control Strip…" button.

Comment: Thank you; I couldn't find this anywhere else and it's so much easier than the alternatives!

Answer (score 10):

You can setup a keyboard shortcut of your choice by creating a **Service** using **Automator**.

1. Open **Automator** (<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> then enter `Automator`).
2. Create a new **Service**.
3. In the left pane, pick **Utilities** → **Run Shell Script** (or use the search field), and drag it into the **Actions** pane (the right one).
4. Just above that action, select *Service receives **no input** in **Any Application***.
5. Enter `"/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession" -suspend` as the text of your shell script (be sure to include the quotes).
6. **Save** your service and give it a name.
7. Open **** → **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** → **Services** → **General** (at the very bottom of the list).
8. Make sure the service you’ve just created is checked/enabled.
9. Click *none* to assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

Now try your keyboard shortcut. You'll be kicked to the login screen. It might appear as though this logs you out, but it does not.

The service is also accessible from the **Menu Bar** → **Application Name** → **Services**. I think the very first time I set it up, I actually had to click it from there before the keyboard shortcut worked, but that might have been a fluke.

If you prefer to sleep your display instead of locking the screen, use `pmset displaysleepnow` as the shell script. This will put your display to sleep, though in that case your screen will only lock after the set timeout specified under **** → **System Preferences** → **Security** → **General**. You could even go crazy and setup both services.

Comment: If you're a developer who is already using a shell, you can skip the whole Automator thing:  

    osx_logout() {
      "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession" -suspend
    }

Comment: @WuTheFWasThat although, since it doesn't actually log you out, I wouldn't call it 'osx_logout'... :)

Comment: If it doesn't work and you use a non-standard shell (e.g. zsh) it might help to set the shell for the script explicitly to /bin/bash in automator. At least it did in my case.

Comment: Indeed, had to set shell to /bin/bash, default of /bin/false did not work.

Comment: Why is it disconnecting my VPN? if I use the native combination Ctrl+shift+power on my air sierra it's not disconnecting at all but with this shell command is... I just want the equivalent of Windows+shift+L that we have on windows to leave my desk and protect with password my screen but let everything just intact on background. :(

Comment: Sorry @Phong I've written the same solution at my post but found your's too late. Sometimes I'm blind :) don't be angry ;)

Answer (score 4):

Hold down the power button for about a half second. This will sleep the computer. If you have it set to lock when the computer sleeps, you're good to go. However, if you hold it down too long, it will ask to restart the computer.

Edit: As [ingenious](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/61205/ingenious) stated, some keyboards do not have a power button. In that case, attempt to locate a sleep button or try another method.

[image: Sleep button]
<sub>(source: [andrels.com](https://www.andrels.com/wp-en_US/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/7010941r_03.jpg))</sub>

Comment: there is no power button on the external (usb/bluetooth) apple keyboards.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org/) and define a key binding/shortcut. I use

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt"}, "S", function()
      hs.caffeinate.startScreensaver()
end)
```

in my `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua` sequence to bind  <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to the screen saver; that I have set to "Require a password `immediately` after sleep or screen saver begins" in **System Preferences → Security & Privacy**. You can also use

```
hs.caffeinate.lockScreen()
```

but I prefer the screen saver approach. See the [Hammerspoon docs](http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/index.html) for all the automation magic it enables.

Answer (score 4):

You can put your mac to sleep with <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>⌽⏻</kbd>.

Before that, have the setting as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: System Preferences > Security & Privacy]

Works for me on macOS Sierra!

Comment: The Unicode character used in the third button doesn't display for me. Is it meant to be [the power symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_symbol)?

Comment: @Flimm Yes! That's what it is, **the power button**.

Answer (score 1):

Apple removed has removed this shortcut for security purposes & due to issues with bluetooth connectivity.
You can utilize **Hot Corners** as a work-around.
*System Preferences>Desktop & Screen Saver*[image]
You get to choose what hot keys trigger the action
When I hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> and drag my mouse to top left corner, my computer locks it's screen.

Comment: Can you please clarify something? Is this only for Bluetooth keyboards? For example, if I upgrade my MBP and do Control+Shift+Eject on the wired or built-in keyboards, would that lock the screen, and would Control+Option+Command+Eject on those keyboards shut it down? Also, would that second keyboard shortcut work over a Bluetooth keyboard? Also can you confirm if any duration is needed to hold those keys to perform either shortcut? Personally I don't use the Control+Shift+Eject shortcut often, but I always use Control+Option+Command+Eject and this question and this answer has me worried.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using a MacBook Pro that's running MacOS Sierra, version 10.12.4. Coming from a Windows and Ubuntu background, I found it odd that a Mac doesn't have an easy shortcut for locking the computer. However, what worked for me are these steps:

1. Go to `System Preferences >> Security & Privacy`.
2. Choose the `General` tab.
3. Set your Mac to require a password **immediately** the screensaver starts or your computer wakes from sleep.
4. Finally, whenever you want to lock your computer, just press the key combination of `Ctrl + Shift + Power button`.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS Sierra 10.12.6, I used the Keychain Access application > Preferences > Show Keychain Access in menu bar.

I've just upgraded to macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 and that preference is no longer there.

Thanks to @pjc90 above, I now know about the "Lock Screen" option in the Apple menu, and the keyboard shortcut (finally) "Command ⌘ + Control ⌃ + Q".

Answer (score 0):

I needed this and was able to accomplish it with the following Apple Script inside of a shell script that does some other stuff, but this should be all you need:

```
osascript <<EOD
        tell application "System Events"
                key code 12 using {control down, command down}
        end tell
EOD
```

Answer (score -2):

To lock screen:

press control + Command + Q

Comment: Also you can change the shortcut from control + Command + Q

https://maclovin.org/blog-native/2017/high-sierra-set-a-global-shortcut-to-lock-screen

Comment: How does this differ from other answers which have given this shortcut and more information?